# how to reload page after click in a href new chrome version 73.xxx

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

in the new chrome 73.xxx is not wotking any more,
does any body have any solution?

Edit

after click just refresh but do not redirect to the href

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to refresh the page

```
window.location.reload();
```